# rabbitMQ reading one flushes other values out of the que as well

Tags: java, rabbitmq

here is the problem I have:

I want to write 2 objects into `rabbitMQ` and only read 1 ( this is a testing to ensure that my data stays in `RabbitMQ` if reader suddenly stops e.g. `ctrl+c`).
I don't have problem with writting to MQ but when I read only one object and close the `connection` the other object disappears too. I don't know why that happens.

I followed the instruction given at : [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html)

creating a channel:

```
 ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
 factory.setHost("127.0.0.1");
 factory.setPort(5672);
 Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
 Channel channel =  connection.createChannel();
```

writing into rabbitMQ (no problem with writing to MQ )

```
channel.queueDeclare("myque", false, false, false, null);
channel.basicPublish("", "myque", null, "one".getBytes("UTF-8"));
channel.basicPublish("", "myque", null, "two".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

the way I read is :

```
QueueingConsumer consumer =new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume("queuethroughProxy", true, consumer);
//while(true){
   QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
   String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
   System.out.println("message is : " + message);
//}
connection.close();
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing two mistakes here.

1. Not setting channel.basicQos(1) --> which leads to bringing all messages in queue from ACK to NACK when you run your consumer program.
2. Enabling Auto ACK while consuming --> which leads to acknowledging all NACK messages on stopping the consumer program.

These are the reasons you are loosing all the messages in queue though you consumed one.

You can refer [my blog post](http://www.prathapchowdary.com/page2/) here for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are confused on the line

`QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();`

One might think as calling `consumer.nextDelivery()` will get the next message from the broker.

But if you see the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) it says, "*Since the server will push messages asynchronously, we provide a callback in the form of an object that will buffer the messages until we're ready to use them. That is what QueueingConsumer does.*"

Since auto_ack is enabled, once the consumer is created immediately server will push the 2 messages to the consumer. *consumer.nextDelivery()* just iterates through the messages that are already received at the client side.